# Elastic search 6.2 with java API, how to have auto generated ID?

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I want to insert data with an autogenerated ID. I insert an "user" like this :

```
java.util.Map<String, Object> jsonMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        jsonMap.put("username", user.username);
        jsonMap.put("password", user.password);
        jsonMap.put("mail", user.mail);
        jsonMap.put("friends", user.friends);
        jsonMap.put("maps", user.maps);
        IndexRequest indexRequest = new IndexRequest("users", "doc",user.username)
                .source(jsonMap)
                .opType(DocWriteRequest.OpType.CREATE);
```

Here, user.username is my ID. And if I remove this argument, I have an error on execution because I don't have any ID for my user. (I tried that because I read that if I don't put any ID, I should have an auto incremented ID).
I didn't find anything on the documentation to help me (or maybe I didn't understood it).

Comment: It seems from the docs, that `IndexRequest` has an `id()` method that should return the id of the indexed document (see . https://static.javadoc.io/org.elasticsearch/elasticsearch/5.0.0/org/elasticsearch/action/index/IndexRequest.html#id--).

Comment: I still have the same error "Validation Failed: 1: an id must be provided if version type or value are set;"

Comment: Try with `DocWriteRequest.OpType.INDEX` .

Answer (score 1):

I resolved my problem. I needed to put the opType to "INDEX" instead of "CREATE". Then I can use the id() function